# Deezer ask for a valid redirect uri

Tags: deezer

When I'm trying to authenticate a user it tells me I need a valid redirect uri.

Where can I change, fix or add it?
I am using the Deezer javascript SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to complete 2 steps:

- Create an application on http://developers.deezer.com
- Set the right domain for that application. For example, YOUR_APPLICATION_DOMAIN.com is right, http://www.YOUR_APPLICATION_DOMAIN.com is wrong.

Setting a wrong application domain in the Edit section of your application will make the user login fail with the following message: "You must enter a valid redirect uri".

Comment: This is now wrong. Apparently they have changed it. Now you HAVE to preprend http://.

Comment: @haffla This answer is still correct. It's saying that the app domain must not have the protocol prepended, which is still the case. However your call back URL and terms URL must have the protocol prepended - perhaps that's what you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error until I removed the http:// from the "application domain" parameter defined at developers.deezer.com.
ie. use: application domain: subdomain.example.com rather than http://subdomain.example.com